Series in Distributions
Given $u \in \mathcal{E}',$ study the converge of the series (geometric and exponential) $\sum u^{k}$ and $\sum \dfrac{u^{k}}{k!}$ in $\mathcal{D'},$ where $u^{k}$ indicates the convolution with itself $k \in \mathbb{N}$ times. Consider, for example, $u = \delta.$
In this exercise, I tried to do particular cases and conclude by induction but it doesn't work. I also tried to use the Urysohn Lemma and the definition of multipication by a smooth function to find the relationship between $u \in \mathcal{E}'$ and the converge be in $\mathcal{D'}$. What can we solve that? Is that idea correct or is there  some better than that?

Have you studied the Fourier transform of distributions?

I suppose that the notation $u^k$ was used in the exercise, but a common notation for $\underbrace{a*\cdotsa}_{\text{$n$ copies of $a$}}$ is $a^{k}.$

Yes, I have studied

Then perhaps looking at the Fourier transform might be useful; $\mathcal{F}{u^{k*}}=\mathcal{F}{u}^k,$ where the righthand side uses ordinary pointwise power.
